# compression nut size for refrigerator water inlet valve

Tags: plumbing, water

I have a Kenmore Coldspot refrigerator that has a compression male thread at the water inlet valve.  The model # is 10650562991.

I am trying to connect the copper flexible tubing that you buy as a kit to the water inlet valve.  The manual on line does not indicate thread size only that it is a compression nut.

I need to purchase an adapter so the 1/4" flexible copper line can be connected to refrigerator.

Can you provide me with the correct female compression nut size?

Comment: It looks like it should be attached to the copper line you described. http://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/666055/kenmore-coldspot-106.html?page=8

Comment: You need a 1/4" compression nut and a 1/4" compression ferrule. This is with the assumption that neither you or anybody else have used any fittings or adapters when making connections to the unit prior to this effort..